# Как удалить ImageMagick-last-libs ?

Tags: centos

надо удалить ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.i686.
перепробовал и в ручную файлы удалить и

```
# yum remove ImageMagick
```

но удалить все равно не получается. Подскажите как?
Centos 6.5

Comment: вообще то это вопрос на руткод. Но не забудьте уточнить, что имеется ввиду под "не удается удалить" - ругается, перезагружается машина, вспышка слева появляется.

Comment: 1. спасибо за замечание, создал тему там, тут можно ее удалять.
2. всмысле? просто не знаю как удалить. не получается. что бы не делал это все не то.

Comment: А как не получается-то? Ну ладно, не здесь. А здесь могу дать совет: отформатируйте винт. Не поможет -- тогда уж молотком.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как: 1. не приведён вывод команды. 2. не указано, как автор определил, что «не удаляется».